# LTspice:Time step too small

Tags: ltspice, simulation

I'm simulating a circuit in LTspice with third party spice models added to it. I encountered several errors but got them solved with the help of many forums. The last error message was "Analysis:  Time step too small; initial timepoint: trouble with u3:40ua-instance j:u3:12" I tried the following as it was recommended here on stackexchange.
[image: attempt to fix]

But now I'm not getting the desired results. My circuit is shown below, it is a biasing circuit of an RF PCB which should give 50 V on "Vout" node and -5-0V regulated voltage on "Vgate". This circuit is taken from Ampleon application note AN11130. Schematic file is attached below. Any help would be highly appreciated.
[image]

Regards
Munazzah

P.S. I'm trying to attach the schematic file pf LTspice with this, but don't know how to do this.

Comment: What component is U3?

Comment: Maybe there is a convergence issue meaning that the circuit solver cannot find a proper solution. I know the error says "timestep too small" but that could be a result of that. What I usually do in such cases is to start the simulation with all voltages = 0 V (zero volt). So change the supply voltage source from a DC source to a pulse source. Then make the supply voltage start at zero, keep it at zero for (for example) 1 us and then ramp it up (also in 1 us) to the desired value.

Comment: Try reading [this](http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Convergence_problems?), but with the amount of subcircuits in there it will be difficult. However, it could be that the 3rd party subcircuits are to blame, such as that `LM` in there (if you had uploaded a larger picture, it could have been seen better). Try replacing it with `UniversalOpamp2` with adjusted settings to match the `LM`'s. I can't see what the other ones are (`U12` and `U13` I think, and those on the bottom left side), but those, too, may be replaced by something frm the official database.

Comment: U1 is LT42461 (hot swap controller IC)